# Automatically Encrypt And Forward An E-mail

Tags: email, backup, encryption

I'm looking for some mechanism to receive e-mail, automatically encrypt it and forward to another e-mail address.

Essentially, I want to this new e-mail address to be an 'off-site backup' of all my e-mail.

Is there any easy way/tool/Outlook feature or something that would do that?

Comment: You could use an Outlook rule to do this.  You just would have to set Outlook to ALWAYS encrypt/sign the email.

Comment: But I'd like for other e-mail sent from Outlook to not be encrypted.  Is that possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution?